# html submit links

Tags: html

I want to create a submit link instead of a submit button.

It looks like any ordinary link (blue and underlined) and when you click on it, the form is submitted.

Edit: is it possible to do this without javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No js, only CSS

```
<input type="submit" value="ABC" style="background:none; border-width:0px; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" />
```

Comment: Almost perfect... I suggest to add cursor:pointer , like this :  style="background:none; border-width:0px; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;"

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit();return false;">submit form</a>
```

**Edit:**

This page:

http://www.beginningjavascript.com/Chapter4/exampleSubmitToLinks.html

has styled a button to look like a link, but it still uses Javascript to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue; text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/AQDcD/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do this easily enough:

See: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$('.submit-link').click(function(){
  $('#form-id').submit();
});
```

Comment: can we do this without any jquery/javascript

Comment: You could style your `<input type="submit" />` to look like a link by removing padding, margin, border etc. but I don't believe so, otherwise. Someone may put me right, though.

Comment: Chances are that, if you link it from Google, that it will be cached on the client's machine anyway. Besides, even though I come from a time where keeping files as small as possible was incredibly important, 60-70k or so isn't that big a deal these days, let's be honest. It may be lazy coding but it also may open the original questioner's eyes to a whole new world of increased usability and impressive, adaptable validation plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the button to look like a link. i.e.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; border: 0; color: blue;" />
```

I'd do it with a stylesheet, rather than the inline styles, but you get the picture.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this simply by using jquery!

Just do the following code ---

```
$('.your-sumbmit-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.your-form').submit();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can do that too. But for simplicity use Jquery.

Comment: Jquery is another layer that makes things more complicated for really simple tasks such as submitting a form

Comment: As you wish, but I recommend using Jquery because you do much more with. And now a days Jquery is used in almost every site to create it user-friendly and amazing looking.